# Problem with too large table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I'm trying to make a large table with latex, but I have a problem with text inside it, it depasses, the page.

here the code :

```
 \begin{table*} \centering
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{2}}}*{2}{l}@{}}  
 \toprule
 Source & La commission de contrôle procède à une véritable évaluation  des   conséqu-   \\  & ences sur l'investissement public.\\
 \hline
     Cible & The control commitee carries out a true evaluation of the  impact on public  \\  & investment. \\ \hline  Référence  & The
 control commitee carries out a true evaluation of the impact on gove- 
 \\ & rnment investment. \\ \hline

 %\textsc{Trig-seq}${_{m-n}}_{sel}$ & it must take into account the
 fact that insurance companies \textbf{need} \\ & \textbf{of of} some
 time.  \\ \hline ${Trig_{m-n}}_{(k)} + ML$    &  The control commitee
 carries out a true assessment of the impact on pu- \\  & blic
 investment \\ \hline  ${Trig_{m-n}}_{(k)}$ &  The control commitee
 process to a true assessment of the impact on pu- \\  & blic
 investment \\ \hline   ${Trig_{m-n}}_{(sel)} + ML$  & The control
 commitee procède to a true evaluation of the conséquences on   \\ &
 public investment.  \\ \hline         ${Trig_{m-n}}_{(sel)}$  & The
 control commitee procède to a correct evaluation of the conséquences  
 \\ & on government investment.  \\ \hline                     \toprule
 \end{tabular*}  \caption{Exemple de traductions d'une phrase issue du
 corpus \textsc{Europarl} avec les différents modèles de
 traduction\label{exemple}} \end{table*}
```

Here attached the image of the resulting table[image]

Any idea to help me please?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please, can you remove `>` on beginning lines of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l X @{}}  \toprule
Source & La commission de contrôle procède à une véritable évaluation  des   
conséquences sur l'investissement public.\\\hline
Cible & The control commitee carries out a true evaluation of the  impact on public 
investment. \\ \hline  
Référence  & The control commitee carries out a true evaluation of the impact on 
government investment. \\ \hline

\textsc{Trig-seq}${_{m-n}}_{sel}$ & it must take into account the
fact that insurance companies \textbf{need} \textbf{of of} some time.  \\ \hline 
${Trig_{m-n}}_{(k)} + ML$    &  The control commitee
carries out a true assessment of the impact on public investment \\ \hline  
${Trig_{m-n}}_{(k)}$ &  The control commitee
process to a true assessment of the impact on public investment \\ \hline   
${Trig_{m-n}}_{(sel)} + ML$  & The control commitee procède to a true evaluation of 
the conséquences on public investment.  \\ \hline         
${Trig_{m-n}}_{(sel)}$  & The control commitee procède to a correct evaluation 
of the conséquences  on government investment.  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}  
\caption{Exemple de traductions d'une phrase issue du
  corpus \textsc{Europarl} avec les différents modèles detraduction\label{exemple}} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For automatic lines break you need to use adequate column type. For example `p{<width>}` or `X`, if you use `tabularx` environment (which I prefer):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \toprule
Source      &   La commission de contrôle procède à une véritable 
                évaluation des conséqu ences sur l'investissement public.\\
    \hline
Cible       &   The control commitee carries out a true evaluation of the  
            impact on public   investment. \\
    \hline  
Référence   &   The control commitee carries out a true evaluation 
                of the impact on government investment. \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}  
\caption{Exemple de traductions d'une phrase issue du corpus \textsc{Europarl} avec les différents modèles de traduction} 
    \label{exemple}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]